# Improving speed of affine transformation of an array using intrinsics

Tags: c++, avx, avx2

In a performance sensitive code, I have to perform am affine transformation of a vector:
`Y=a*X+b`
where `Y` and `X` are vectors and a and b are scalars.
As a quick-and-dirty way to improve the speed of the computation, I delegated parallelization to openMP
`#pragma omp simd` directive. Having some spare time, lately I tried to implement it directly using intrinsics, getting more or less the same performance as the `omp` solution.
Is there a way to beat the OMP vectorization? I can use up AVX2 instructions.

The code below is tested under windows 10, compiled with VS 2019.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <chrono>
#include <immintrin.h>

///Computes y=alpha*x+beta
inline void SumAndSetOmp(
    arma::Col<double>& y        /**< Result*/,
    const arma::Col<double>& x  /**< Input*/,
    const double& alpha         /**< Coefficient*/,
    const double& beta          /**< Offset*/)
{
    auto* __restrict lhs = y.memptr();
    const auto* __restrict add_rhs = x.memptr();
    const auto& n = x.n_elem;
#pragma omp simd
    for (arma::uword i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        lhs[i] = add_rhs[i] * alpha + beta;
    }
}

inline void SumAndSetSerial(
    arma::Col<double>& y        /**< Result*/,
    const arma::Col<double>& x  /**< Input*/,
    const double& alpha         /**< Coefficient*/,
    const double& beta          /**< Offset*/)
{
    auto* lhs = y.memptr();
    const auto* add_rhs = x.memptr();
    const auto& n = x.n_elem;
    for (arma::uword i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        lhs[i] = add_rhs[i] * alpha + beta;
    }
}

inline void SumAndSetAVX(arma::Col<double>& y       /**< Result*/,
    const arma::Col<double>& x              /**< Input*/,
    const double& alpha                     /**< Coefficient*/,
    const double& beta                      /**< Offset*/)
{
    //Allocate  coefficients
    const auto alphas = _mm256_set1_pd(alpha);
    const auto betas = _mm256_set1_pd(beta);

    //Extracting memory addresses
    auto* __restrict pos_lhs = y.memptr();
    const auto* __restrict pos_rhs = x.memptr();

    //Computing sizes
    const unsigned int length_array = 4;
    const unsigned long long n_aligned = x.n_elem / length_array;
    const unsigned int remainder = x.n_elem % length_array;

    //Performing AVX instruction
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < n_aligned; i++) {
        const __m256d x_avx = _mm256_loadu_pd(pos_rhs);
        const __m256d y_avx = _mm256_fmadd_pd(x_avx, alphas, betas);
        _mm256_storeu_pd(pos_lhs, y_avx);
        pos_rhs += length_array;
        pos_lhs += length_array;
    }

    //Process the rest serially
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < remainder; i++) {
        pos_lhs[i] = alpha * pos_rhs[i] + beta;
    }
}

enum method
{
    serial,
    omp,
    avx
};

arma::vec perform_test(const arma::vec& x, const method mtd, int trials = 100, const double alpha = 3.0, const double beta = 5.0)
{
    arma::Col<double> res(x.n_elem);

    const auto beg = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    switch (mtd) {
    case serial:
        for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
            SumAndSetSerial(res, x, alpha, beta);
        break;
    case omp:
        for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
            SumAndSetOmp(res, x, alpha, beta);
        break;
    case avx:
        for (int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
            SumAndSetAVX(res, x, alpha, beta);
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "time:" << std::chrono::duration<double>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - beg).count() << "s\n";
    return res;
}


//Benchmarking
double test_fun(long long int n,int trials=100, const double alpha = 3.0, const double beta = 5.0)
{
    const arma::Col<double> x(n, arma::fill::randn);
    
    const arma::Col<double> reference = alpha*x + beta;
    std::cout << "Serial: ";
    const auto res_serial = perform_test(x, method::serial, trials, alpha, beta);
    std::cout << "OMP: ";
    const auto res_omp = perform_test(x, method::omp, trials, alpha, beta);
    std::cout << "AVX: ";
    const auto res_avx = perform_test(x, method::avx, trials, alpha, beta);
    // errors wrt the reference
    const double err_serial = arma::max(arma::abs(reference - res_serial));
    const double err_avx = arma::max(arma::abs(reference - res_avx));
    const double err_omp = arma::max(arma::abs(reference - res_omp));

    //Largest error
    const double error = std::max(std::max(err_serial, err_avx), err_omp);
    if (error> 1e-6)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Something is wrong!");
    }
    return error;
}

int main()
{
    test_fun(10000000);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't armadillo do operations like that natively? Do you have only AVX2 or FMA as well? How big is `n`?

Comment: I tested with Eigen (which I know does do a lot of optimizations behind the scenes) and it generates pretty similar to asm to the intrinsics version you used here, so you might be pretty close to optimal for what you can do. I second the question wondering about `n` (since if that's known at compile time, you could optimize further). It might be worth peaking at the assembly to make sure the benchmark is actually working (i.e. it's not optimizing all your code out), and would be worth playing around with compile flags if this is performance critical (-O3 for sure)

Comment: Armadillo delegates these to the compiler, for instance it does not even uses ?axpy for these kind of operation.
Value of n it is dynamic, usually in the range 1000-10000.
instruction wise, I assume a fairly recent processor, having all instruction but AVX512

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at improving on your solutions, but I think they are optimal, so you're best sticking with `omp`.

*The following is speculative and goes beyond your question:*

*If it's an option you could try omp's multithreading, I'm always surprised at how low the number of elements at which you get a reasonable boost is, though 1000 elements with a simple affine transform I expect would be too low.  If other parts of your algorithm are parallelisable then this is more likely to be helpful.*

*If you can afford to change your problem and don't need double precision you could work with floats.*

Comment: I use this code in a parallel section, that is why I went through the intrinsic route, to try to squeeze the most out of it.